# "...saw someone out...": grammatical role of "out"?

Tags: adjectives, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

Sentences:

> My dad is **out** on vacation.
>
> I saw her **out** on a bicycle.

Is the word **out** an adjective in this context?

Or is the word **out** the short form of **out of home?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, not directly related to your question, but "saw someone out" is also an idiom that means "removed that person from the building".

Answer (score 5):

[Wayne Goode](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/229309/32) gives you the traditional analysis.

A more contemporary analysis (Huddleston & Pullum, *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) treats *out* in these sentences as an *intransitive preposition*—that is, one which does not require an explicit object but constitutes a full-fledged preposition phrase by itself.

Note that ordinary transitive preposition phrases can act as *locative complements* to verbs, including subject and object complements which describe the position or path of the subject or object:

> My dad is ***on the roof***.
>   I saw her ***on the bikepath***.

Intransitive prepositions can act the same way.

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, if you use "out" by itself, "My dad is out", it is an adjective.  If use "out" with a phrase after it as in these examples, it is an adverb. [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/out)

In the second example, because the verb "saw" has more than one meaning, if the sentence is shortened to  "I saw her out",  it can mean either "I saw her outside/away from home/etc." or "I escorted/showed her out of the building."

Comment: What would be the grammatical role of "out" in the second meaning of "I saw her out" (i.e. "I escorted her out of the building")? Is it a preposition?